# Dynamic object mapping using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON request of the form:

```
{
  "type": "Car"
  "data": {
      "object": {
          "id": "1"
          "color": "Red"
          "plate": "J124D"
      },
      "owner": {
          "name": "John"
      }
  }
}
```

Now, the type field dictates the content of the object field. In the example above, the type = Car means the object container will have id, color and plate fields. But, if the type = Plane, the Object field will have id, wingspan, manufacturer etc. Basically, the type field will dictate dynamically what Java object corresponds to "object". I am fairly new to Jackson, so I was looking for some pointers on how to achieve this type of dynamic mapping in code. So far I have this,

```
public class Request {
    @JsonProperty
    String type;

    @JsonProperty
    Data data; // Probably need a custom deserializer here?
}
```

The other difficulty is the usage of Request. Data would probably have to be cast into something like CarData or PlaneData so that callers could easily do request.getType() and then extract data from the request casted to the appropriate type of data (Car or Plane).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON with Jackson into Polymorphic Types - A Complete Example is giving me a compile error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362446/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into-polymorphic-types-a-complete-example-is-giv)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it is using a `Map<String, Object>` to map the `data` property:

```
public class Request { 

    private String type;
    private Map<String, Object> data;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

You may find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39917533/1426227) useful.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt quite follow. Can you perhaps leave a small code example to explain. Much appreciated

Comment: @JohnBaum This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39917533/1426227) may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Create a POJO for object tag. Using JSONObject class you can map the value to java POJO accordingly.

Ref: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: If its not too much trouble, do you mind posting a short example of how to do this or a link to an external resource? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please go through provided link