# How to add all @PostMapping parameters to a Map?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-web

I want to provide a `POST` servlet that takes the following `JSON` content:

```
{
  "name": John
  "age": 25,
  "some": "more",
  "params: "should",
  "get": "mapped"
}
```

Two of those properties should be explicit mapped to defined parameters. All other parameters should go into a `Map<String, String>`.

Question: how can I let `Spring` map them directly into the map of the bean?

```
@RestController
public void MyServlet {
   @PostMapping
   public void post(@RequestBody PostBean bean) {

   }
}

public class PostBean {
   private String name;
   private String age;

   //all other json properties should go here
   private Map<String, String> map;
}
```

Comment: Did you consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916520/mapping-a-dynamic-json-object-field-in-jackson ?

Comment: That would require an extra "payload" parameter in the json. But I cannot change the JSON that get's posted.

Comment: That post contains useful link in commentaries: http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class PostBean {
    private Map<String, String> map;

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, String> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setMap(String name, String value) {
        if (this.map == null) map = new HashMap<>();
        this.map.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: When posting answers, it's important that you post more than code, make sure to explain your answers

Comment: Well, the question is how to add all parameters to the `Map`. The answer is simple and the code provides a complete example. The clear difference between the question and answer is the `@JsonAnyGetter/Setter`. So no need to write further explanation.