# Mapping varying JSON to Java objects

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I have the following problem: 
I need to convert incoming JSON to Java objects, however, I don't always get the same incoming object (the format of the messages is varying). Sometimes it is a list, with custom elements:

```
[ 12, [100, 100, 100] ]
```

and sometimes it is an object:

```
{ key: 'value' .. }
```

I also need to convert the list to an object, not a list.

However, I know the format of the possible objects, but I cannot determine which one I get before I could parse it. What would be a good technique to map these to Java objects? Trying to parse with each object type and catching the formatting exceptions, or something else?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39917533/6503002